# Convergence of integral with a parameter

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am having trouble tackling the following problem:

Let $\alpha >0$ does the following integral converge? If so, for what values of $\alpha$ does it converge?

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{(arctan(x))^2}{x^\alpha } dx 
\end{equation}

I have tried finding the analytical integral using integration by parts but have not succeeded.  Is this necessary?

Comment: It is not necessary to find the explicit integral (in fact, it looks very hard). Do you know of any results on comparison of integrals?

Comment: Ah ok! Do the same rules apply as for infinite series? No i have not worked on improper integrals yet.

Comment: I don't know exactly what rules you have for infinite series, but typically similar rules apply. You have nothing about this in your book?

Comment: I will inform myself on comparison of integrals.  I just thought there might be an easy way to integrate it that I had not thought of.  Any specific technique to look at?

Comment: Hint: Try to compare with $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ and $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ to find what $\alpha$'s that are permissible.

Comment: I know you are only asking for convergence, but in case the closed form interests you, we can find a closed form using Ramanujan's Master Theorem: Let $s$ be any number such $0<\operatorname{Re}s<1$. Then we have $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{( \tan^{-1} x )^2}{x^{1+2 s}} dx = \frac{\pi \operatorname{csc}( \pi s)}{2 s} \left( \frac{\gamma}{2}+\psi(1+2s)-\frac12 \psi(1+s)\right).$$ Wher $\psi$ is the digamma function.